# What's the use case for a Bootstrap success button?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I'm immersing myself in Bootstrap 4, trying to fully understand it and become adept at using it to rapidly develop user interfaces. It's possibly just a semantic thing, but I'm failing to understand the use case for e.g. a Bootstrap success (or info) button. I can see the utility of the colour coding for alerts - what the user has just done can be notified as successful or otherwise. But that is presumably something which occurs AFTER a button is pressed, as an outcome of the button action. But why/when would you click a 'success' button, which triggers an action?

Comment: The success, danger, etc are purely to tell you what color they are and has zero to do with how you choose to use them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the "Success" button can be used in situations when you want the user to agree with the action that is going to be performed. For example, user modifies some data in the form in modal and in order to confirm or cancel the change, you can use "Success" button with the label "Confirm" and  "Danger" button with label "Cancel".

Comment: Ah, OK, it makes sense when expressed like that. On that basis, using 'btn-info' for a straight 'OK' button in an alert makes sense too.